# how to define a php config file that define constant and use it any where in project

Tags: php, constants, config

how to define a config file that i can use it any where whole project without include every where?

Answer (score 13):

There are two ways,

1. **[define()](http://php.net/define)** : 
   The constants you define using define method is available to the whole project.

   ```
   define('SITE_URL' , '/path/to/docroot/');
   echo SITE_URL;
   ```
2. **Class constant** : A class constant is available to the whole project.

   ```
   class MyConfig{
       const SITE_URL = '/path/to/docroot/';
   }
   echo MyConfig::SITE_URL;
   ```

Comment: how to use it in any where whole project?

Comment: for example i need to use this definetion in index.php (whitout include "config.php")

Comment: if these codes are in 'config.php' then you must include it in `index.php` otherwise write these codes in `index.php`.  If this code doesn't execute it wont magically add 2 constants in the current execution head.

Comment: If const value is an array or nested array, it is not easy for IDE ( PhpStorm ) to show candidate items.

Answer (score -1):

you can define constants in a single config file f.e in config.php and then include it into your project where you need

Comment: now i do this, but i want to use constant without include every where

Comment: how to define a config file that i can use it any where whole project without include every where?

Answer (score -1):

Use `auto_prepend_file`

For using localhost such as XAMPP or WAMP:

1. Go to php.ini
2. Find "auto_prepend_file" and change to `auto_prepend_file="xampp/htdocs/dir.php"`
3. Restart your apache service to make it work.

   - Refer to [this site](http://jesin.tk/php-auto_prepend_file-and-auto_append_file/) for more information

If that didn't work or you don't have access to php.ini, try modifying an .htaccess file (I haven't tried this method yet though)

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/real/path/to/file/file_name.php"
```

- Refer to [this site](http://www.xpertdeveloper.com/2012/02/prepend-append-files-with-htaccess/) for more information

Comment: That's a terrible solution - you're coupling the web server with the software!