# PHP server define

Tags: php, apache2.4

I have 2 servers for my PHP project, one for prod and one for tests.

I want to add to the test server a flag to use it in every PHP file. For example to add `define('TEST', true)`

How can I put this define in the "server level"? I mean that it will be define in the `ini` or somthing, not in PHP page.

Comment: You can try using environment variables instead.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550223/set-an-environment-variable-in-htaccess-and-retrieve-it-in-php

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427681/how-to-define-a-php-config-file-that-define-constant-and-use-it-any-where-in-pro

Comment: They are in the `.htaccess` file. I don't want to set this flag in any file that can be upload later to the prod server.

Comment: Why an env var? You could simply check the name of the server, e.g. hostname, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, etc... There will be SOME different between your prod and devel servers that you can check for without explicitly setting a flag for it.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles No, my main problem is where can I define it.

Comment: @nrofis You should define it in your server config (e.g. [Apache SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html#setenv)).

Comment: @cbuckley How? I didn't find example for this. My servers are Apache 2.4

Comment: The link is above, or [here for 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use environment variables for this.

In Apache, for instance, you can use [mod_env](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html) to set an environment variable in your `VirtualHost` directive for your test server:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV testing
```

And for your live server:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production
```

You would then use it in PHP:

```
$environment = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');

if ($environment == 'testing') {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It can be written in every place, not just in the `VirtualHost`

Comment: The [Context of SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) is "server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess". The lines above are directly from my own `VirtualHost` blocks :-)

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I like to use `` $myname = `hostname`; ``

Then if the hostname is the name of my test server, put it in test mode.

Alternatives exist, such as checking the `HTTP_HOST` if you're working on a subdomain. Or you could find out the port being connected on if you use the same domain but another port.

Basically, anything that makes them different, can be used as a check to put you in test mode.

Comment: OP wants a flag for the application environment (test/prod etc), not a variable for the server name.

Comment: @cbuckley Okay, the whole point of this answer is that you could, for instance, do `if( $myname == 'test.machine.foo') define("TEST",true);`